# VBA-Excel Copy Data to Excel From Site - New Cell Creation & HTML issues

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel

I will outline my task. I have an Excel Sheet and I wish to write code to instruct IE to navigate to a URL specified in a cell, copy information from web page and paste to Excel. Go to next URL listed in Excel in same window of IE and then paste to the next cell.

I have the code to get to the page etc. But all of the HTML is one Table so I cannot use the 'Get Data' function of Excel. Also the info once retrieved via this method cannot be 'vlookup'd.

I believe there is some work on the parent child functions of HTML to drill down the data, because at the moment it is copying the info, but also the style etc of table.

Also some information only appears in the HTML as a link to another URL. If I could use code to copy the product as opposed to the constructive code that would be useful.

There is also an issue with automating the select cell for url and pasting of the information. Will I have to write every instance? There will be around 400 requests.

The URL is UN & PW protected but I can paste the HTML element to help.

Thank you so much.

This is what I have thus far:

```
Private Sub blahblah_Click()
Dim ie As Object
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WB = Workbooks("hopef.xlsm")
Set WS = WB.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie

    .Visible = True
    For Each URL In Range("A2")
        .Navigate URL.Value

Do While ie.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)

Loop

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)

p = ie.Document.getelementbyid("adviser_fund_wrapper").innerHTML
WS.Range("B1").Value = p

Next
With ie
    .Visible = True
    For Each URL In Range("A3")
        .Navigate URL.Value

Do While ie.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)

Loop

y = ie.Document.getelementbyid("scheme_assets").innerHTML
WS.Range("c1").Value = y

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)

y = ie.Document.getelementbyid("adviser_fund_wrapper").innerHTML
WS.Range("d1").Value = y

Next
End With

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. Also this might not be the correct answer and too long for a comment hence posting as answer.

here some pseudo:

```
Open the browser
loop through the cells contain URL values
    Navigate to the url
    Search and find the value in the html section
    paste the value in the result column next to the URL column (like if url column is A3, result column will be .Range("C" & loopCounter))
    Search another value in HTML and paste on another result column

loop end
```

regarding iterations in the parent loop. loop until you find an empty cell in Range("A:A")

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I have used to do something similar, you just need to modify it to make it work!

```
Dim dataextract As String

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

With ObjIE
.navigate ActiveCell.Value
End With

objIE.Visible = False
Do While objIE.readyState <> 4 And objIE.Busy
DoEvents
Loop
'Do While objIE.readyState > 4: Loop

'Call Sleep
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))


On Error Resume Next

dataextract = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName(Putstuffhere)
If objIE.document.getElementsByTagName(Putstuffhere).innerText <> " " Then
Do code.
Else
Do different code
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = dataextract

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Loop
```

This code, once edited, will pull back specific data into the cell adjacent to your input data and loop until finished.